# How do I deploy my Python application as a distributable package

Tags: python, windows, deployment, build, production

I am new to deployment with Python. I have finished my python application and tested it too. I want to release it as an application (like the commonly used apps) for Windows (for now). I did look around other answers and also tried some blogs for the process.

At the time, I have tried *py2exe*, *pyinstaller* and also a simple *self-extracting archive*. But what I want is a simple distributable setup or application release which I can provide to the users and not requiring them to install python or any of my dependencies externally.

**pyinstaller** does the packaging and also fulfills my requirements but **my code has some async** functions (specifically awaiting the functions from requests module), and **after the pyinstaller build finishes, my code does not wait for them** and executes all along like synchronous code. This makes my program crash.

I need this solution to simple to implement, so that I may ship this system quickly.

### Edit

These are the sequence of commands I am using to build my application. Both host and target platforms are Windows Machines (x64 preferably).

To build the application in the current directory using pyinstaller.

```
$ pyinstaller -i logo.ico -n Engine engine.py
```

**engine.py** is the entry point of my app and I read the docs of pyinstaller and **Engine** is the name of the App (just a fancy name).

This gives me two folders **build/** and **dist/** in the current working directory. I get the *Engine.exe* in the dist/ folder, but as stated does not wait for async methods to complete and exits before they even log their results to the console.

Comment: Can you show the sequence of commands you are using to package your system currently? I take it this is a GUI project rather than a web-based Electron-style app?

Comment: Not exactly a GUI app, rather a Command line app. Without any framework, just some llibraries. More like a web-automation project. I'll update my post with the sequence of commands I am using.